# Update array in a config file

Tags: bash

I have an array in a file

```
MY_CONFIG = ['1','2','3']
```

How can I update it's values in a bash script? I need to modify it to

```
MY_CONFIG = ['4','5']
```

Comment: use `sed` tool ...

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus for now I have sed -i "s/^\(MY_CONFIG = \).*/\1 ['4','5'] /" file but wanted to know if there is a solution better suited for arrays

Answer (score 0):

Like so as a bash array:

```
MY_CONFIG=("1" "2" "3")
MY_CONFIG+=("4" "5")
```

Using sed on a file:

```
sed "s/MY_CONFIG = ['1','2','3']/MY_CONFIG = ['4','5']/g" filename
add -i to sed to make it permanent.
```

Comment: This is for a config file that contains multiple arrats

Comment: Yep, this will just insert it into brackets on every array. Are you using this array for bash processing, or for another program? If you can use bash arrays programmatically it's easier. Else if you need to edit a specific array in a file, you could always find and replace the entire array sequence, to ensure that you edit the right one. `sed "s/MY_CONFIG = ['1','2','3']/MY_CONFIG = ['1','2','3','4','5']/g" filename` You can do this more programmatically with read. or for loops. Provide an example of the file, containing the array for more advice.

Comment: The question is not about appending, but replacing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: `[` and `]` are special characters in a regex.

Comment: I suggest to replace first `[` and `]` with `\[` and `\]`.

Answer (score 0):

To change only the array `MY_CONFIG` with `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/MY_CONFIG = \[.*\]/MY_CONFIG = ['4','5']/" file
```

Comment: Much neater solution wildcarding bracket contents!